# C++ How to design a class that can take on only a discrete set of values, e.g. Red Green Blue

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Say for example that we want to design a color class, assuming that we only allow for 3 different color values: Red, Green, Blue.

How is this generally achieved in C++? Or better what is the general design pattern for this?

The only way I could think of, is to initialize 3 different static colors in the Color class, make the colourCode inaccessible and allow construction of a new Color only with an already existing one.

```
class Colour
{
public:
    static const Colour Red;
    static const Colour Green;
    static const Colour Blue;

    Colour(){}

    bool operator==(const Colour &other) const{
        if(other.colourCode == this->colourCode){return true;}else{return false;}
    }

    Colour & operator=(const Colour & other){
        this->colourCode = other.colourCode;
    }

    Colour(const Colour & other){
        *this = other;}

private:
    int colourCode;

    Colour(int colourCodeIn){
        colourCode = colourCodeIn;
    }
};

const Colour Colour::Red(1);
const Colour Colour::Green(2);
const Colour Colour::Blue(3);

class Pen
{
public:
    Pen(){}
    void setColour(const Colour & infarbe){
        farbe = infarbe;
    }
    Colour farbe;
};

int main()
{
    Pen myPen1;

    myPen1.setColour(Colour::Blue);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how about using an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `enum` or `enum class`.

References:

- [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) has all details and covers exactly your `RGB` example.
- [Alex Allain](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html) elaborates benefits of `enum class`es also illustrated with `RGB`.